# pandas: "cannot reindex from duplicate axis" when I apply some loc operation using unique indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrama called df, and when I apply `df[df>10]` I got "cannot reindex from duplicate axis", by this exception:

```
In [150]: df[df>10]
.
.
.
~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _can_reindex(self, indexer)
   3097         # trying to reindex on an axis with duplicates
   3098         if not self.is_unique and len(indexer):
-> 3099             raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
   3100 
   3101     def reindex(self, target, method=None, level=None, limit=None, tolerance=None):
```

However I verified that:

```
In [151]: df.index                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[151]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=150001, step=1)

In [152]: df.index.is_unique                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[152]: True
```

So, df.index.is_unique is True but the verification "not self.is_unique" is not working properly.

I have tested with other DataFrames and I got no problems, but using a large one (df.shape is (150001, 792)) I got this error, and I already verified that I have unique indexes.

**Moreover**, doing this:

```
In [177]:  new_df = df.reset_index(drop=True) 
In [178]:  new_df[new_df > 10]

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _can_reindex(self, indexer)
   3097         # trying to reindex on an axis with duplicates
   3098         if not self.is_unique and len(indexer):
-> 3099             raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
   3100 
   3101     def reindex(self, target, method=None, level=None, limit=None, tolerance=None):

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

So, it's 100% sure that we have no duplicates here, so what is going on?

Comment: I would personally go with `df[df.index>10]` or even better `df.loc[10:,:]`. Not sure if `df[df>10]` is meant to work

Comment: @erncyp This gives me all rows with index > 10, in fact this works, but that's not the question/problem here. df[df>10] verifies all values > 10, not just the index of the rows.

Comment: What version of pandas?

Comment: @ALollz Version 1.0.1

Comment: I see! yeah, it seems like a legit bug then, hope the fix it via github!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize, the problem was found in columns name + numpy specific values from np.array

If you want to know more about this bug, I opened a issue in [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31954).